# thaOpen OS X Finder from link in text file

Tags: macos, finder, links

Is it possible to create an "internal" link that opens up a specific folder window in Finder?
If not possible native, I remember seeing a plugin that did something similar, but can't remember the name.

Edit: I need this inside a personal wiki app to link to reference folders or files. Not one folder or file, but a lot of different files or folders.
I would want something like file:///Users/username/projectfolderABC1 that then opens that location in finder.

It probably doesn't exist natively, but looking for some plugin or similar way to accomplish this.

Comment: Try using the `open` command from the terminal. As in `open /Users/BOB/Documents`.  When you get what you want, put it in a script and link the script wherever you want it.  I am too lazy to open my mac and test it right now but it *should* work.

Comment: Why do you need a link? Why not just use an alias? Do you want this to work for any Mac from a web page?

Comment: Answers, see my edit